# Spring batch application freezes abtruptly without log and error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-graphql

I am facing strange issue with my application.
I have Spring boot + batch application which is internally calling API to get some data and we are calling API using GraphQL.
It is working fine 9/10 times for same set of data but getting freezed one time without giving any error/warning in the logs.
Logs are half processed and freezed when calling API. I need help to fix this issue as I am not able to figure out how to debug this issue.

Comment: Did you enable debug logs? Where is the app hanging exactly (ie, what is the last line in the debug logs?). The app could be hanging waiting for the API call to return. Do you have a timeout set on the call? Without more details, it is impossible to know the root cause of your issue.

Comment: This issue is happening in production and working fine in lower environments
To debug that I need that application to break at same point and I am actually looking for a way to replicate it in lower environments.

Comment: To add more yes we do have timeouts and retries but application is getting hung up at some point of time where feels like JVM dies or processes dies suddenly inbetween execution.